# How to uninstall MiKTeX on OSX?

Tags: miktex, installing, mac

I downloaded MiKTeX for OSX instead of MacTex, and as someone who's not well versed in how Terminal works and where everything is stored, it's been difficult to troubleshoot and find proper documentation. As I ran into problems, I would just Google the errors and apply random fixes blindly. Now my Frankenstein of a set up isn't able to perform certain functions that I could at the beginning, and I think I need to restart.

I'm not even really sure where MikTeX is installed, and if I could delete those files, I don't know how that would affect any connections and symbolic links, or if it would affect future installations (like when install MacTex).

I installed using HomeBrew based on these instructions: https://miktex.org/howto/install-miktex-mac

```
brew tap miktex/miktex
brew install miktex
```

The only documentation I could find on uninstalling came from this page, but I don't think it applies to me, as typing those commands into Terminal didn't do anything. https://miktex.org/howto/build-mac

Note: I think I removed all symbolic links using `initexmf --admin --force --remove-links` when I was following uninstall instructions. I don't know how to add them back and I'd rather just reinstall fresh.

Comment: Can you just do: `brew uninstall miktex --force` ?  Also, if you install MacTeX from here: http://www.tug.org/mactex/ you should get things working, I suspect without any trouble.

Comment: thanks @AlanMunn I did not know it worked like that. I actually installed MacTeX just now while MiKTeX was still installed hoping it would overwrite all the directories and it seems like it's working better already

Comment: That sounds a bit dangerous. Because if the MikTeX install isn't finished, it might overwrite some things that MacTeX has done, and you might end up with a bit of a mess.  So you should definitely remove the `brew` version once it finishes, using the command I suggested and then you may have to reinstall MacTeX. (But that's quite simple to do.)